# how to use tower-cli to schedule a job

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I have an ansible-tower template that I want to run at a specific time in the future. To do this I believe I should run `tower-cli schedule create` then pass some parameters to the program, however I don't know how to pass the date/time parameter.

I have looked at [this](https://tower-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_ref/resources/schedule.html) document however it doesn't seem to include such a parameter. How does one do this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, based on [some example issues](https://github.com/ansible/tower-cli/issues/453) that they are using the [`RRULE` property from the iCalendar](https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-8-5-3-recurrence-rule.html) but why they would omit such a crucial detail from every single document in the Internet I can only chalk up to "please buy Tower and pay us all the $$$$$$$$"

Even the [help text](https://github.com/ansible/tower-cli/blob/v3.3.4/tower_cli/resources/schedule.py#L128-L129) for `schedule.py` is abysmally useless.

I hope knowing that it is RFC-5545 compatible helps unstick you from your problem, and I hope you [file an issue](https://github.com/ansible/tower-cli/issues/new) against tower-cli letting them know that you were not provided very basic information to be successful with their tool.